# softHSM integration with Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hsm, softhsm

I am trying to integrate softHSM with Hyperledger Fabric. I have followed the below steps:

1. I have cloned the repo from this link
   https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca (main-branch)
2. Executed the below 3 commands from the above directory. After execution, I got the new binary and the new Fabric-CA image.

   make fabric-ca-server GO_TAGS=pkcs11

   make fabric-ca-client GO_TAGS=pkcs11

   make docker GO_TAGS=pkcs11
3. I have replaced the old binary(fabric-ca-client and fabric-ca-server)
4. I am trying to spin up the Fabric-CA in the docker container and passing the environment variables as per the official documentation.

   ORG1_RCA:

   ```
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.5.1
    container_name: ORG1_RCA
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ORG1_RCA
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_BCCSP_DEFAULT=PKCS11
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_BCCSP_PKCS11_LIBRARY=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/libsofthsm2.so
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_BCCSP_PKCS11_PIN=
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_BCCSP_PKCS11_LABEL=
    ports:
      - 7054:7054
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    environment:
     - SOFTHSM2_CONF=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/config.file
    volumes:
      - ./fabric-ca/verizon:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - /home/softhsm/config.file:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/config.file
      - /usr/local/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/libsofthsm2.so
    networks:
      - contract
   ```

**I am not providing the PIN and label for security purposes.When I am running this container, the private keys are still getting saved into the msp/keystore folder instead of HSM.**

Comment: I don't believe we ever fixed the issue we have with overriding BCCSP config via environment variables.  Can you try setting the BCCP values in the actual fabric-ca-server-config file instead?

Comment: I have cloned the official fabric-ca repo from GitHub and run this command (fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw) to start the server natively. After running, I can see few certificates and one config file. 

Then I modified the bccsp section to use PKCS11 format in the config file and restarted the server.

These steps are fine or do I need any other configuration?

Comment: that should be correct

Comment: I modified the config file to use the PKCS11 interface and restarted the CA server.


Now, I can see three private keys(**IssuerRevocationPrivateKey, IssuerSecretKey and 6f753f4708a755a53d450732eeff8103486c6eb188efa1108f7cd958517f00e8_sk**) are present inside msp/keystore folder.


How can I be sure the private kets are stored inside HSM?